# Terminated due to memory error iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management

I am working on a project where I need to manage videos. I need to rename or delete video. For that we need to hold the video in NSDATA and then manage it.
But I am getting an error message as Terminated due to memory error on below statement.

**Edited**

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.path];
if (data){
    BOOL success = [data writeToFile:videopath atomically:NO];
}
```

self.path contains the path of video file. It works in small size video (of 4-10 mins) But it crashes in large size video (bigger than 20-30 mins).

Please advice.

Comment: please explain what is the "self.path". i think you need to check first that if data is fetched or not . before "writeToFile".

Comment: please put whole code and what is `self.path` here ?? file name of full path with filename ?

Comment: I have updated the question now. Please advice

Comment: @sanchitsingh Why do you need to read the video file data for renaming/deleting the file? Cant you use `NSFileManager` APIs for this? For rename use `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` and for deleting use `removeItemAtPath:error:`

Comment: is it happening on simulator or device?

Comment: Are you trying to load locally saved files or trying to download large video file from network?

Comment: @Amar Your logic is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead loading the video file to memory, Your code will work with small files but u gonna fail with big files.

```
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source] ){

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:nil];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are maintaing the full video as `NSData` inside the application. Instead of using a Video file as `NSData`, copy the video to some where (e.g [NSTempoaryDirectoy](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2154&p=14000)). You can delete or rename the Old video.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the requirement for you. from your question I understood that you need to rename your video file. for renaming, why we need to go for reading it as NSdata and again writing the same. for Renaming try the below code.

```
NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSString *target = [[filePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newnameofthefile];

    [filemanager moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:target error:nil];
}
```

I hope this may help you..